# ¿Que diferencia hay entre un hashmap y treemap?

Tags: java, diccionarios

**Hashmap :**

```
HashMap<Integer, String> hash = new HashMap<>();
```

**TreeMap :**

```
TreeMap<Integer, String> tree= new TreeMap<>();
```

Mi duda se debe a que si existe alguna diferencia que se usa exactamente igual y no encuentro la diferencia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seguramente un compañero con más experiencia podrá aportar y profundizar más, pero, grosso modo, la diferencia está en que en un **HashMap** las claves no están ordenadas (o no se garantiza ese orden), mientras que en un **TreeMap** se pueden ordenar.

Por lo general, un Hashmap es más eficiente salvo que necesites ordenar las claves, para lo que usarías un TreeMap.

Comment: muchas gracias cualquier ayuda es buena y si entendiste la pregunta no te olvides de la fecha hacia ahora mismo te doy el check